# Set width for mat-grid-list from Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, grid

I have one column composed of 3 lines and each line has a height of 200px.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="200px">

  <mat-grid-tile rowspan="1" style="background-color: lightblue">
    FIRST
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile rowspan="1" style="background-color: #EDC2EC;">
    <mat-card-content style="text-align: center;">
      <p style="font-size: xx-large;">ALWAYS FREE</p>
      <p style="font-size: large;">Great for occasional use</p>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile rowspan="1" [style.background]="lightpink">
    third
  </mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-list>
```

But how to set a width for my rows ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no width property given to the MatGridListModule in Angular Material docs.

So to achieve width, we can try Using cols and colspan properties together,

For Example,
If we want to divide the row into 3 parts, We can give cols=3 in mat-grid-list.
And we can use colspan property in mat-grid-tile.
It all depends on what is our requirement.

**UPDATE**

To meet the requirement as you mentioned in the component,
We can use cols property which will give you a column layout and **gutterSize** property to provide margin between them

Check an example snippet like below

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="200px" [gutterSize]="'40px'">

  <mat-grid-tile style="background-color: lightblue">
    first
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile style="background-color: #EDC2EC;">
    second
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile style="background-color: lightcoral">
    third
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile style="background-color: orange">
    fourth
  </mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: with this there is 2 rows and not 3, basically what i am trying to do is like in this page https://www.cloudeasier.com/index.php/plan/

Comment: with 4 mat grid list and for each mat grid list 3 rows

Comment: Edited the above sample code, Hoping it meets your requirement

Comment: it is 4 columns for one row, what i wanted is 1 column and 3 rows, and still don't know how to set width, i changed my mind to mat card